# Is there a way to limit/throttle how many cells in a Google Sheets column are executing at a time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't even know how to word my title. But basically in my GSheets I have a column that has a script and I want to limit how many cells at one time are executing the script. To throttle the executions - because 100 lines of data are imported but the route the script calls can't handle a large load so I end up having a bunch of !ERRORS and have to manually resubmit that data. I added in the script.

```
function myFunc(value)
{
 var serviceUrl = "myUrl" + value;
 var response;
  try
  {
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  finally
  {
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(response.myValues);
    return arr; 
  }


}
```

Comment: It's definitely possible - show the script so we can make modifications to achieve this.

Comment: You can create a script that is forced to respect, the API quotas imposed by the url you are requesting from, by using [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) for example. But please provide some code so we can take a look

Comment: Hey I added the script @ross

Comment: What are you going to do with `arr`?

Comment: I'm returning the values into the sheet - since it's like a 2D array it fills the row. @Cooper

Comment: Yes but what the basic idea of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's the input?What's the expected output? What the process in between input and output? Don't use programming or cell functions to explain it.

Comment: The input is a string which is passed as a query parameter into the url that I have to call. The output is a JSON object. This information seems unrelated to answering the question. How do I limit how many cells at a time are triggering the function? @Cooper

Comment: What do your error logs say?

Comment: Error Log says that request timed out. Because API is unable to respond on time. @Aerials

Comment: @search-learn Have a look at [these restriction](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_limitations) from the Apps Script side

Comment: @Aerials I looked at those restrictions, the URL fetch has a limit of 20,000 and I haven't even gotten close to that. And the custom function execution is 30 seconds. Well when there are more than 10 requests pinging the external API it does take longer than 30 seconds. So that's why I need to figure out how to limit how many cells are triggered at a time.

Comment: You know exactly what you need to tackle now. Please ask a new question, with you script logic, so we can take a look, as there are many ways to go about this

Answer (score 0):

### You seem to be running into API quota limits of your requested site.

I would recommend that you stop erroneus data from being pasted in the sheet. By using a try-catch as you are, but tailor it to your needs.

#### Example:

```js
function myFunc(value) {
  var serviceUrl = "yourUrl" + value;
  var arr = [];
  var response;
  try {

    // Try something that might throw errors
    response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(serviceUrl);
    Logger.log(response.getContentText());
    response = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    arr.push(response.myValues);
  }
  catch(err)  {
    // Catch any errors gracefully and handle them
    Logger.log(err);
  }
  finally {
    // This will always run, so make sure it is something that will not 
    // put erroneus data in your sheet
    if (arr.length > 0){
      Logger.log("Response content is: " + response);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I understand the concept of the suggestion. But if 100 rows are populated at the same time, 100 calls will instantly be made to the API. And like you said I will hit the quota limit. So how do I setup my Google Sheets to handle, let's say only 10 cells at a time. To basically queue them instead of making 100 calls immediately but rather only 10 at a time?